# KL-divergence of two distributions using probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am reading an article stated that:

Given $\mu$ is a probability measure, a measurable set $A$, and $\hat{\mu}(\cdot) = \mu(\cdot \bigcap A)$, then $D_{KL}(\hat{\mu}||\mu) = - \log \mu(A)$.

How do they get this result? I worked around with the KL divergence but cannot get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly $\hat \mu\ll \mu$; and since $\hat \mu(X) = \mu(X)/\mu(A)$ for any measurable $X\subset A$, the Radon-Nikodym derivative $d\hat \mu/d\mu = 1/\mu(A)$. Thus
$$D_{KL}(\hat \mu||\mu) = \int_A \log \frac{d\hat \mu}{d\mu} = -\log \mu(A).$$

Comment: Shall it be $\int_A \log \frac{d\hat{\mu}}{d\mu} d\hat{\mu}$?

Comment: Depends on how lazy you are in writing out the integral. :)

Comment: Thank you. can you explain why $d\hat{\mu}/d\mu = 1/\mu(A)$. I tried this: $\frac{d\hat{\mu}}{d\mu} = \frac{d(\mu(X)/\mu(A))}{d\mu(A)}  = \frac{\frac{d\mu(X)}{d\mu(A)}\mu(A) - \mu(X)\frac{d\mu(A)}{d\mu(A)}}{\mu(A)^2} = \frac{1}{\mu(A)} \times \left(\frac{d\mu(X)}{d\mu(A)} - \frac{\mu(X)}{\mu(A)}\right)$. The last term cannot reduce. Any suggestion?

Comment: Just use the definition of the Radon-Nikodym derivative, namely that $\hat \mu(X) = \int_X d\hat \mu/d\mu\,d\mu$. It's not an elementary-calculus-style derivative.